# Unable to catch error using redux-saga? (while making a firestore call via react-native-firestore)

Tags: redux-saga, react-native-firebase

Would the below code the correct way to "catch" errors in redux-saga using call or fork?  That is when I have the "createItem" function is this correct to NOT catch any errors here and assume this will pass back any exceptions to the generator function "createItemSaga" to catch?

A 2nd question here is I'm noting that I am getting a firestore error passed back (I'm using react-native-firebase) however I am NOT catching it with this code.  Refer to console output below.  I create a security rule to reject the attempt to create an item in firestore backend to test this.

```
function createItem(item) {
  firebase.firestore().collection('todos').add(item);
}

export function* createItemSaga() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(ActionTypes.AddListItem_UIRequest);
    console.log('createItemSaga: received AddListItem_UIRequest');
    const { item } = action;    
    yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRequested });

    try {
      console.log('createItemSaga: createItem Start');
      yield fork(createItem, item);
      console.log('createItemSaga: createItem Ended');  // <-- This is reached! But why.
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('createItemSaga: error caught. Error=');  <-- Why isn't this point reached
      console.log(pf(e));
      yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRejected });
    }
  }
}
```

The console output is:

```
createItemSaga: recived AddListItem_UIRequest
createItemSaga: createItem Start
createItemSaga: createItem Ended

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. (firestore/permission-denied).
Error: Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. (firestore/permission-denied).
    at createErrorFromErrorData (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1822:15)
    at /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1775:25
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:2133:16)
    at /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1950:16
    at MessageQueue.__guard (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:2068:9)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1949:12)
    at /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/debuggerWorker.js:126:58
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/debuggerWorker.js:35:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:213:7)
```

Note: Did raise potential issue here is case it is related to this libary: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/727

ADDITIONAL NOTES:

- I get the same result if I use "call" instead of "fork" in the line "yield fork(createItem, item);"
- I also get the same results if I incorporate the update attempt in the generate like the following:

Code:

```
export function* createItemSaga() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(ActionTypes.AddListItem_UIRequest);
    const { item } = action;
    yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRequested });
    try {
      console.log('createItemSaga: createItem Start');
      firebase.firestore().collection('todos').add(item);
      console.log('createItemSaga: createItem Ended');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('createItemSaga: error caught. Error='); 
      console.log(pf(e));
      yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRejected });
    }
  }
}
```

ADDITIONAL NOTES 2:

- Get same results when I turn the "createItem" function into a generator:

Code:

```
export function* createItem(item) {
  try {
    console.log('createItem: Start');
    firebase.firestore().collection('todos').add(item);
    console.log('createItem: End');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('createItem: error');
    console.log(pf(e));
  }
}

    export function* createItemSaga() {
      while (true) {
        const action = yield take(ActionTypes.AddListItem_UIRequest);
        const { item } = action;
        yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRequested });

        try {
          console.log('createItemSaga: createItem Start');
          yield call(createItem, item);
          console.log('createItemSaga: createItem Ended');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('createItemSaga: error caught. Error='); 
          console.log(pf(e));
          yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRejected });
        }
      }
    }
```

Console:

```
createItemSaga: createItem Start
createItem: Start
createItem: End
createItemSaga: createItem Ended
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. (firestore/permission-denied).
Error: Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. (firestore/permission-denied).
    at createErrorFromErrorData (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1822:15)
    at /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1775:25
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:2133:16)
    at /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1950:16
    at MessageQueue.__guard (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:2068:9)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:1949:12)
    at /Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/debuggerWorker.js:126:58
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/Greg/Dropbox/source_reactnative/gcTodo/.vscode/.react/debuggerWorker.js:35:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:213:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not get it working using createItem as a separate function, however am now catching the error by contracting all into the one generator per the below:

```
export function* createItemSaga() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(ActionTypes.AddListItem_UIRequest);
    const { item } = action;
    yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRequested });
    try {
      const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('todos');
      yield call([ref, ref.add], item);
      yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemFulfilled });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('createItemSaga: error caught. Error='); 
      console.log(pf(e));
      yield put({ type: ActionTypes.AddListItemRejected });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think `createItem` should be a generator (or in other words a saga). And then you don't need a `fork` but `call`. That is because `fork` is not blocking while `call` is. That's why you are getting the console log. I guess if `createItem` is a generator your `try-catch` block will work.

Comment: I get the same result if I use "call" instead of "fork" in the line "yield fork(createItem, item);"

Comment: also same result if I incorporate the update line into the generator - have put this code at the end of the question to show

Comment: not this if this now points to an error in the underlying react-native-firebase library I'm using for firebase?  i.e. does this confirm it is this library not correctly capturing the error, or should my redux-saga code we are looking at it catch this exception in any case?

Comment: But did you make `createItem` a generator? Like `function* createItem`.

Comment: Yes I get the same result as a generator.  I put the code up at the end of the question (if this is what you meant?)

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Is `firebase.firestore().collection('todos').add(item)` throwing an error in this case. I mean if you wrap it in a try-catch block are you able to catch the error.